# Very irritating white highlighting of code blocks in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, highlight

I can't seem to get rid of this. It started some weeks ago and I have tried searching through potential extensions that may be causing the problem to no avail.

Attempted to toggle extension settings and to see if any are problematic.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it. And add a screenshot.